# Python for loop but no loop is performed

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

In the code below, I have a GUI with an OptionMenu and a button that performs a function when clicked. When I choose first option from the dropdown list and then click the button, it should loop through each item in my `statements` array.

For example, I want the below combinations, which each combination will trigger the function behind the button (to produce results and write into a new line in a file).

1. First Option - First Statement
2. First Option - Second Statement
3. First Option - Third Statement

Later on when choose Second Option, it will again loop through First/Second/Third Statement.

Maybe my for-in loop is in the wrong position, because when I click the button, there was only one result recorded in the file and it has a wrong result (I am not too worried at this because my function is to calculate the sentence similarities so it could be picking the wrong var/string). And it will stop after one run, no loops happening.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import tkinter
import SemanticSim

from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

a = IntVar()

var1 = StringVar(master)
var1.set("-- Choose One Option --") # initial value
var2 = StringVar(master)
x3 = StringVar()
x3.set("Click the button to get result...")

master.title("Graphical User Interface")
master.geometry("800x600")

##########################################   METHODS  ##############################################
def ButtonClickMethod():
    a = var1.get() # get the text value of selected menu option 
    var1.set(a) # sets value to label when needed to, label needs to be set in specific manner
    x1 = var1.get()
    a = var2.get()
    var2.set(a)
    statements = ["First Statement", "Second Statement", "Third Statement"]
    for statement in statements:
        x2 = var2.get() # if I put `statement` in the bracket, I get this error: "TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
    x3.set(SemanticSim.SemanticSimilarity(x1, x2));
#############################################################################################

b3 = Button(master, text="Calculate Results", command=ButtonClickMethod)
b3.place(x=100, y=200)

label1 = Label(master, text="Choose One Option ")
label1.place(x=20, y=100)

option1 = OptionMenu(master, var1, "First Option", "Second Option", "Third Option")
option1.config(width=50)
option1.pack()
option1.place(x=200, y=100)

CaptionLabelResult1 = Label(master, text="Semantic Analysis Result: ")
CaptionLabelResult1.place(x=50, y=250)

LabelResult1 = Label(master, textvariable=x3)
LabelResult1.place(x=200, y=250)

mainloop()
```

Comment: What's `comments`? Did you mean `statements`?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be doing anything with the strings in `statements`. Also -- what's with the semicolon? Python isn't like Java or C.

Comment: I don't know much about `StringVar`s but it looks like `var2` is not defined - do you mean `var1`, and also getting a variable 3 times in a row is not going to do anything.

Comment: @JohnColeman this line `x3.set(SemanticSim.SemanticSimilarity(x1, x2));` is where something will run in the background. `SemanticSim` has the big function that will do the job.

Comment: But the loop isn't *doing* anything with `statement` -- also, terminating that line with a semicolon is a mistake. You can learn the language how you want to, but it seems like an odd approach to be experimenting with tkinter before learning the basic language syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
import tkinter
import SemanticSim

from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

a = IntVar()

var1 = StringVar(master)
var1.set("-- Choose One Option --") # initial value
var2 = StringVar(master)
x3 = StringVar()
x3.set("Click the button to get result...")

master.title("Graphical User Interface")
master.geometry("800x600")

##########################################   METHODS  ##############################################
def ButtonClickMethod():
    a = var1.get() # get the text value of selected menu option 
    var1.set(a) # sets value to label when needed to, label needs to be set in specific manner
    a = var2.get()
    var2.set(a)
    statements = ["First Statement", "Second Statement", "Third Statement"]
    for statement in statements:
        x1 = var1.get()
        x2 = statement
        x3.set(SemanticSim.SemanticSimilarity(x1, x2));
#############################################################################################

b3 = Button(master, text="Calculate Results", command=ButtonClickMethod)
b3.place(x=100, y=200)

label1 = Label(master, text="Choose One Option ")
label1.place(x=20, y=100)

option1 = OptionMenu(master, var1, "First Option", "Second Option", "Third Option")
option1.config(width=50)
option1.pack()
option1.place(x=200, y=100)

CaptionLabelResult1 = Label(master, text="Semantic Analysis Result: ")
CaptionLabelResult1.place(x=50, y=250)

LabelResult1 = Label(master, textvariable=x3)
LabelResult1.place(x=200, y=250)

mainloop()
```

This works.

Answer (score 2):

```
statements = ["First Statement", "Second Statement", "Third Statement"]
for statement in statements:
    x2 = var2.get()
```

Apart from the fact that `var2` does not exist in your code (which causes an error with your example), the `statement` is never used within the loop body, so since there are three iterations, what happens is this:

```
x2 = var2.get()
x2 = var2.get()
x2 = var2.get()
```

That’s not really useful and also will not be affected by the choice of the options before.

Comment: this line `x3.set(SemanticSim.SemanticSimilarity(x1, x2));` is where something will happen in the background. `SemanticSim` has the function that will do the job by calculating the similarities between `x1` and `x2`

Comment: But that line comes *after* the problematic part. Currently (with `var2` missing) it will not even run, and even so, `x2` is always the same, regardless of the statements (which I have no idea what you’re trying to do with).